# SQL Server Difference : Web Edition vs Express Edition With Advanced Series

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I know this sounds dumb but just for curiosity, I am asking so.

I am developing a web app on Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit). My client has SQL Server 2008 Web Edition. So I just want to know about the compatibility issues or any feature differences between the two, as I have to deploy the express edition on web edition.

Please note : we don't have any advanced features implementation like Reporting, Analysis, BI. We have simply CRUD operations with triggers and views etc. We might execute jobs for backup on our server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express and Web edition are exactly the same code base, exactly the same database file format - no problems to be expected here.

You can either:

- deploy using SQL scripts against the new Web edition database
- or you can even backup / restore your database from your Express edition to the Web edition server

The more important point is: it has to be the **same version**, e.g. both **2008**, or **2008 R2** - don't mix those! You cannot restore a newer version backup onto an older version SQL Server (e.g. you could not backup your SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database and then restore it to a SQL Server 2008 Web edition instance). The path using SQL scripts always works, though

Comment: Thanks marc. You mean I can deploy the db of different version via scripts. Restoration will not work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AmitRanjan: backup/restore only works on identical version, or "upwards" - you can backup on 2008 and restore on 2012 - but not the other way around